# Defined Array Variable working fine but child element not working in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Facing an Weird Issue in Vuejs.. I am using firestore to get data using props as id for the singlepost...
Now array formed is fine.. as you can see in the screenshot... there is no error in the console, i am seeing data... but its not working for its child key element.. attaching another screenshot of code.i guess if {{temple}} is working then {{temple.templename}} should work fine also

```
<div class="appCapsule">
{{temple}}
         <div class="section mt-2">
            <div class="card text-center">
                <div class="card-header">
                    {{temple.templename}}
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <img v-bind:src="'https://awesong.in/jain/storage/temples/' + temple.fileToUpload1" style="width:100%">

                    <p class="card-text">Temple Type : {{temple.templetype}}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Near By City : {{temple.nearbycity}}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Built in : {{temple.built}}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Address : {{temple.address}}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Location : {{temple.location}}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">District : {{temple.district}}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">State : {{temple.state}}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Phone : {{temple.phone}}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Email : {{temple.email}}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Website : {{temple.website}}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Views : {{temple.clicks}}</p>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

[Image attached for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuL2j.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temple is an array of JSON objects. You could use `temple[0].property`, or you could loop over it:

```
<div v-for="t in temple" :key="JSON.stringify(t)">
     {{t.templename}} // etc
</div>
```

Comment: how can i get single object, so that i don't need to run loop

Comment: @user3323829 `temple[0].templename`.